# Function Overriding

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, c++17

The code below on compilation shows the following errors :

> (1) invalid covariant return type for 'virtual daughter daughter::display()'
>        daughter display()
>
> (2) overriding 'virtual mother mother::display()'
>         virtual mother display()
>
> (3) conversion from 'mother' to non-scalar type 'daughter' requested
>     daughter d2 = w->display();

The code is the following snippet in C++.

```
class mother {
    public:
     virtual mother display()
     {
        cout<<"This is the mother class"<<endl;
    }
};

class daughter : public mother
{
    public:
    daughter display()
    {
        daughter d1;
        std::cout << "This is the daughter" << std::endl;
        return d1;
    }
};

int main() {
    //code
    mother *w = new daughter();
    w->mother::display();
    daughter d2 = w->display();
    return 0;
}
```

The above function shows error in function overriding and the coherent return values of daughter to daughter. What is exactly wrong with this and what underlying concepts am I missing in this?

Comment: To override a function, it needs to have the exact same signature, including the *return type*. If you add the `override` special keyword when doing your override (as in `daughter display() override`) then the compiler will issue an error message about it.

Comment: Also, if you declare that a function should return a value, then you really must return a value. Not doing that could lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Covariant return types need to be either pointers or references.

Comment: @hyde actually you can return a covariant type

Comment: Suppose I have base class Shape. And it has a virtual function : Translate
And I have a derived class Rectangle.

Now I declare a translate function in Rectangle which will translate The a rectangle ( by say some units ) and return the new rectangle created.

How will I implement this?

Comment: @KudoShinichi: You don't. That is not a thing you should do via inheritance. Dynamic polymorphism is based on pointers/references to derived classes that look and act like some base class. You can't return a "new rectangle", not unless it's a *pointer* to a newly allocated "rectangle".

Comment: @NicolBolas Is there a way I can connect with you regarding this? If you don't mind of course.